# Why installing JUnit Jupiter messed up my path?

Tags: junit, vscode-extensions, junit-jupiter

Before implementing the JUnit Jupiter, my project has the below hierarchy

```
> src 
    > BoardGameProject
        > domain
        > UI
    > images
```

Then, I created a Test folder for JUnit implementation, and created a JUnitTest.java inside of it. Now hierarchy is below:

```
> lib (JUnit install created this folder)
> src 
    > BoardGameProject
        > domain
        > UI
    > images
    > Test 
        > JUnitTest.java
```

After that, I easily installed JUnit Jupiter via VSCode. The problem is that, now I am trying to import many classes inside BoardGameProject->domain or UI. But, when I was working inside BoardGameProject and implementing the classes (that are not tests), I was using imports as

```
import src.BoardGameProject.UI.Frames.BuildModeScreen; // as given example.
```

and had no problem. But, after JUnitTest.java, I had to remove src and make the import as

```
import BoardGameProject.UI.Frames.BuildModeScreen; // as given example
```

I tried

```
CTRL+SHIFT+P -> Reload Window 
CTRL+SHIFT+P -> Java: Clean the Java language server workspace
```

separately. It fixes the error but whenever I tried to open JUnitTest so that I can finally implement tests, the errors start to appear again. What should I do?

Note: This src problem occurs both in test class and regular classes.

Comment: You seem to have a fairly non-standard project setup. Most people and tools use the [Maven layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). If you use Maven (or Gradle) as build tool, you also don't need to install anything, you just configure the build tool to pull in what dependencies you need (here JUnit). If your import statements change, maybe something (I'd blame VS Code) has changed the classpath setting. Try to find that setting and adjust it? Good luck.

Comment: @Robert I also blame VS Code :) But, this is related to my college project, so I manually deleted, even though still it bugs me not to know why. But thank you!